# Communication between PHP and Python with XML-RPC

Tags: php, python, xml-rpc, rpc

I want communicate between php and python with XML-RPC. 
Is it possible to run XML-RPC on different server similar to what is depicted in the diagram below?

[image]
<sub>(source: [picofile.com](http://s2.picofile.com/file/7155452903/Untitled.png))</sub>

Comment: Python supports XML-RPC clients through the class `xmlrpc.ServerProxy` and servers via the Twisted framework and others.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. XML-RPC is language agnostic. PHP has xml-rpc libraries, and so does Python.